# adding provisioning script using REST API

Tags: ibm-cloud-infrastructure

I have used the interactive screen to add provisioning scripts,. but would also like to add them using a SoftLayer REST API. Is there s REST API to add a provisioning script with name and URI?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
https://$user:$apiKey@api.softlayer.com/rest/v3/SoftLayer_Provisioning_Hook/createObject

Method: POst

{  
   "parameters":[  
      {  
         "name":"rcvtest",
         "uri":"https://test.com"
      }
   ]
}
```

**References**:

- [SoftLayer_Provisioning_Hook::createObject](http://sldn.softlayer.com/reference/services/SoftLayer_Provisioning_Hook/createObject)